# How does a consumer microphone achieve a sensitivity of -20 dB?

Tags: microphone, electret, sensitivity

How does a consumer microphone achieve a sensitivity of -20 dB ([Edutige EIM-001](http://www.edutige.net/shop/eim-001/)), when one of the best industrial electret microphones I could find ([Primo EM158](http://www.primomic.com/php/get_products_details.php?model=EM158)) has a sensitivity of only -32dB (1 kHz at 1 Pa)? Is there some internal amplification going on? Didn't I search hard enough?

Comment: Every dB counts! The industrial microphones therefore have close to 33% better sensitivity, which means 33% less gain and distortion required for better end results.

Comment: dB is a log scale.  Ten dB is a big number

Comment: I assume higher sensitivity to be better (-20dB > -32dB), i.e. smaller sound pressures result in a bigger signal and a "louder" result (good for distant and quiet sound source). Am I wrong? (Sorry, I'm not an expert)

Comment: As @ScottSeidman , said that's 12dB better!  13dB would be a factor of 20 in power! (and a factor of ~4 in amplitude.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I never doubted -20dB being better than -32dB and I know dB has a logarithmic scale. The question was, why the consumer product has a better sensitivity value than the industrial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an amplifier (gain would be around 10 or 15, no big deal).

There are 'silicon microphones' with similar sensitivity (-18dB when the internal amplifier is set for +20dB gain) such as [this](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Knowles%20Acoustics%20PDFs/SPM0408LE5H-TB.pdf) one.

SNR is the more important spec (you can always add gain), and the 'consumer mic' is pretty lousy (58dB) vs. 74dB for your electret mic and 63dB for the one I linked to.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the link to that microphone! Still much to learn... The term _MEMS-microphone_ seems to be more common though.